# How to write many and similar python scripts at once?

Tags: python, pytorch

I need to have 100 of those similar python scripts that have `MyData` class from `MyData_1` to `MyData_100`.

```
import torch
import numpy as np
from torch_geometric.data import InMemoryDataset, Data
from torch_geometric.utils import to_undirected

class MyData_1(InMemoryDataset):
    def __init__(self, root, transform=None):
        super(MyData_1, self).__init__(root, transform)
        self.data, self.slices = torch.load(self.processed_paths[0])

    @property
    def raw_file_names(self):
        return "mydata_1.npz"

    @property
    def processed_file_names(self):
        return "data_1.pt"

    def process(self):
        raw_data = np.load(self.raw_paths[0])
        cluster_data = torch.load('./raw/total_clusters.pt')
        x = torch.from_numpy(raw_data['x'])
        y = torch.from_numpy(raw_data['y'])
        
        pos = torch.stack([x,y], dim=-1)
        cp = torch.from_numpy(raw_data['cp'])

        data_list = []
        for i in range(cp.size(0)):
            data = Data(x=cp[i].view(-1,1),pos=pos.view(-1,2),  cluster=cluster_data[0])
            data_list.append(data)

        torch.save(self.collate(data_list), self.processed_paths[0])
```

I'm trying to do this because each `MyData` class calls different `mydata_1,2,...100.npz` to generate dataset.
Is there any way to make this fast?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not just use one class and pass the file name in the constructor?

Comment: "I'm trying to do this because each MyData class calls different mydata_1,2,...100.npz to generate dataset." I can't understand why this would justify using different classes. Hint: why did you (correctly) **not** write a different class for each possible value of `self.data` or `self.slices`?

Comment: Which part is causing most of the slowness? The easiest way to test this before resorting to profiling is to put print statements in your code that tell you the time thats elapsed since the last statement was printed.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I need to call data separately like this: ```dataset_1 = MyData_1(root='./', transform=transform)
dataset_2 = MyData_2(root='./', transform=transform) ... 
dataset_100 = MyData_100(root='./', transform=transform)``` to trace the order of dataset #.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen How could I just pass the file name for example?

Comment: @PaulRooney I think it should be very fast because there's no calculation part at all. It just read from ```mydata_1.npz``` ... ```mydata_100.npz``` and ```total_clusters.pt``` and generate processed datasets from there.

Comment: Isn't `generat(ing) processed datasets` a form of calculation? If you do measure, you might be surprised about how inaccurate your intuitions can be. If you can't optimise the process, have you thought about using [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)?

Comment: `f"mydata_{self.n}.npz"`

Comment: "How could I just pass the file name for example?" The same way that you already pass the `root` path.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't fully understand the reason why you need to create 100 different classes.

Is it because you need to return `mydata_1.npz` to `mydata_100.npz`? If then, You can create a single class like this:

```
class Myclass:
  def __init__(self, index):
    self.index = index

  def raw_file_names(self):
    return "mydata_{}.npz".format(self.index)
```

Then, at another script like `main.py`, you can create/assign it like:

```
for i in range(100):
  exec('dataset_{} = MyData_{}({})'.format(i, i, i))
```

I believe you can build your own code that fits your problem with above examples.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this by creating Metaclass(subclass ) below is a example how to pass dynamic name of class in  subclass magicfunction

> MyDynamicSubclass

```
class MyClass:
    def __init_subclass__(cls, my_name):
        print(f"Subclass created and my name is {my_name}")
        print(cls, cls.__class__.__name__) 



MyDynamicSubclass = type("MyDynamicSubclass", (MyClass,), {}, my_name="Ellis")
```

> output:
> <class '**main**.MyDynamicSubclass'> type

Comment: Technically, you can. But you most definitely should not

Comment: Before giving a negative @MadPhysicist a proper explanation would be more justifiable with any document reference this is really bad that without any justification you giving negatively to my answer

Comment: It's massive overkill to generate a separate class with all its namespace and associated structure when all you want to store is a single variable. It works, but it's terrible advice.